# plotting pandas data frame with unequal data set

Tags: python, plot, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to plot a pandas Data Frame that contain an unequal amount of data points (rows) and I am not sure if this is causing an issue for my plot.

in the below code, the portfolioValue# differs in length

```
portfolioValue1 = 521
portfolioValue1 = 500
portfolioValue1 = 521
portfolioValue1 = 521
portfolioValue1 = 425
```

my pandas data frame shape is

```
(1, 5)
```

Here is the python code:

```
portToPlot = {'AAPL.txt':[portfolioValue1], 'GOOG.txt':[portfolioValue2], 'MSFT.txt':[portfolioValue3],
    'AMZN.txt':[portfolioValue4],'CMG.txt':[portfolioValue5]}

portDFrame = DataFrame(portToPlot)

portDFrame.plot(sharex=True)
```

This is the error I keep getting

```
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: please note that my portfolioValues are basically numpy arrays

Answer (score 0):

They need to be of equal length, for example, we can shorten everything to 425 elements:

```
portfolioValue1 = random.random(521) 
portfolioValue2 = random.random(500) 
portfolioValue3 = random.random(521) 
portfolioValue4 = random.random(521) 
portfolioValue5 = random.random(425) 
portDFrame=DataFrame(zip(portfolioValue1,portfolioValue2,portfolioValue3,portfolioValue4,portfolioValue5))
portDFrame.columns=['AAPL.txt', 'GOOG.txt', 'MSFT.txt','AMZN.txt','CMG.txt']
portDFrame.plot(sharex=True)
```

[image]

But it looks to me that you are working on interday stock data for one year duration. I think the reason some of them are shorter is because there are missing interday price for some trading days. You should have preserved those missing data in the first place rather than just discard them altogether.

Comment: actually the data is going back 10 years, weekly data. In your example, do you mind pointing out how you shortened the data?

Comment: `zip()` does it. `zip(range(5), range(4))` results in `[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]`, which is only 4 elements long.

Comment: using zip() on the shortest amount of data, I get the following error  '''% (len(value), len(cur_axis)))
Exception: Length mismatch (5 vs 1)'''